# My jquery text function is not showing on html

Tags: html, jquery

This is my code

**HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <input class="row 1" type="text">
        <input class="row 2" type="text">
        <input class="row 3" type="text">
        <input class="row 4" type="text">
        <input class="row 5" type="text">
        <input class="row 6" type="text">
        <input class="row 7" type="text">
        <input class="row 8" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
var boxes = $(".row");
var saveBtn = $("<button>").text("complete");
boxes.append(saveBtn)
console.log(saveBtn);
```

why my button is not showing on my web page?

Comment: When does your jQuery code executed ? on clicking something ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to insert a HTML `<button>` inside the `<input>`, you cant do that you cant insert HTML elements inside an `<input>`

You can insert it after it with `.after()` or before it with `.before()`

check this code:

```js
var boxes = $(".row");
var saveBtn = $("<button>").text("complete");
// boxes.before(saveBtn)
boxes.after(saveBtn)
console.log(saveBtn);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <input class="row 1" type="text">
        <input class="row 2" type="text">
        <input class="row 3" type="text">
        <input class="row 4" type="text">
        <input class="row 5" type="text">
        <input class="row 6" type="text">
        <input class="row 7" type="text">
        <input class="row 8" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no it was the error I said this was really helped me sorry

Comment: And I have no idea that reputation is -1.. I actually did thums up

Comment: Its okey bro, glad to help.

Comment: I have some questions about how to save the input values to save to local storage. is it possible?? and how lol I have no idea I used 'saveBtn.on("click", function(e){
    event.preventDefault();'

Comment: yes you can its very easy by just using localStorage.setItem(name, value);

Comment: Check the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage      it contains everything you need.

Answer (score -2):

Change this line

```html
var saveBtn = $("<button>").text("complete");
```

into

```html
var saveBtn = "<button>complete</button>";
```

Comment: That's not an issue. `$("<button>").text("complete");` create a button element with text `complete`.